# Pulsar JVM Dashboard Zookeeper show No Data on column direct memory

Tags: grafana, apache-zookeeper, apache-pulsar

**Describe the bug**

To monitor a Pulsar cluster, I used grafana and in the Pulsar JVM dashboard, Zookeeper Direct Memory is show No Data. While other dashboards have data such as Bookie, Broker, Recovery.

I want to know why Zookeeper Metrics has no data for direct memory. I researched the document but did not find information about zookeeper metrics. Can you help me?

Pulsar version 2.9.2
Zookeeper version 3.5.5
Dashboard Grafana

**Zookeeper**
[image]

**Broker**
[image]

**Recovery**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ZooKeeper does not use direct memory. The Grafana panel on the dashboard is generic and applies to all components, so for Broker, BookKeeper, and Recovery it displays direct memory since those components use direct memory. For ZooKeeper it shows No Data since ZooKeeper doesn't use direct memory.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Can you give me documentation about zookeeper doesn't use direct memory or the Grafana panel on the dashboard is generic and applies to all components. I can talk customer about this.